# Where to find source used in Alpine linux docker image

Tags: docker, operating-system, alpine-linux

Looking at the alpine linux docker page, one of the tags [points to](https://github.com/alpinelinux/docker-alpine/blob/0cc7fea5828303fa14d754bab4f9161a8cac4ba1/x86_64/Dockerfile) the dockerfile on github

```
FROM scratch
ADD alpine-minirootfs-3.12.12-x86_64.tar.gz /
CMD ["/bin/sh"]
```

Where to find the source for this tar?

Comment: It is right there, next to the Dockerfile in the repo: https://github.com/alpinelinux/docker-alpine/tree/0cc7fea5828303fa14d754bab4f9161a8cac4ba1/x86_64

Comment: The Docker images aren't built from source. Here's some docs on how the tars are made: https://github.com/alpinelinux/docker-alpine/blob/master/docs/build.adoc

Comment: @HansKilian after cloning that github repo and running the ,`prepare-branch.sh`  what is does is download tarballs from https://cz.alpinelinux.org/alpine/ so still not where the source for those tarballs are from. Are you seeing different?

Comment: No, I see it the same way. Like I said, "The Docker images aren't built from source"

Comment: I guess my question is, where is the source for the tarballs used by Docker images. Maybe I should change the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can download it from [Alpine Linux releases](https://alpinelinux.org/releases/)

The one the Dockerfile points is [here](https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.12/releases/x86_64/alpine-minirootfs-3.12.12-x86_64.tar.gz)

Comment: If I untar it, I don't see any source. Where are the C files?

Comment: @T.Webster You won't. All Linux distros are really just a bunch of files put together. If you want the source code, you can find the source for the kernel, bash, gcc, systemd, openrc, grub, etc. on their respective repos.


If you want to learn more about how Linux distros are made, you can always check Linux From Scratch. Great source for understanding how everything works, even if you don't make your own distro.


Check it out here: https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/download.html